# If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, are $X^2$ and $Y^2$ identically distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ is distributed like $Y$, can we conclude that $X^2$ is distributed like $Y^2$?

I don't know how to prove it or to give a counterexample.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally...

The fact that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed means that $P[X\in B]=P[Y\in B]$ for every Borel subset $B$. Assume this and consider the random variables $U=h(X)$ and $V=h(Y)$ for some measurable function $h$. Then $U$ and $V$ are identically distributed.

To see this, note that $[U\in B]=[X\in h^{-1}(B)]$ and $[V\in B]=[Y\in h^{-1}(B)]$ for every Borel subset $B$. Considering the Borel subset $C=h^{-1}(B)$, one gets
$$
P[U\in B]=P[X\in C]=P[Y\in C]=P[V\in B],
$$
for every $B$, hence $U$ and $V$ are identically distributed.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed means $$P(X\le x)=P(Y\le x)\\ \mbox{or,}\quad F_X(x)=F_Y(x)\quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$
Then for $x\ge 0$ $$P(X^2\le x)=P(-\sqrt{x}\le X\le \sqrt{x})\\
=P(X\le \sqrt{x})+P(X>-\sqrt{x})+\lim_{h\uparrow 0}P(X\le -\sqrt{x}+h)\\
=F_{X}(\sqrt{x})+1-F_X(-\sqrt{x})+\lim_{h\uparrow 0}F_X(-\sqrt{x}+h)\\=F_{Y}(\sqrt{x})+1-F_Y(-\sqrt{x})+\lim_{h\uparrow 0}F_Y(-\sqrt{x}+h)\\=P(Y^2\le x)$$

Comment: Why the restriction to the range of X? Not in the definition and only complicates things.

Comment: Ok, @Did I've edited it.

Comment: Note that [$P(X\leqslant x)=P(Y\leqslant x)$ for every $x$] does not allow on its own to deduce that $P(-\sqrt{x}\leqslant X\leqslant\sqrt{x})=P(-\sqrt{x}\leqslant Y\leqslant\sqrt{x})$.